# Is 3d writhe for tight rational tangles quantized?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, knot-theory

The 3d writhe of (simple) ideal (i.e. tight) knots is quantized, as Stasiak and colleagues have shown years ago.

**What's the current state of progress on the question whether the writhe of tight rational 3d tangles is quantized?**

One can close rational tangles at spatial infinity. Does this help in solving the problem?

Here is a page that offers prizes for the solution of this and related knot theory problems: [motionmountain.net/charge-mass.html](https://www.motionmountain.net/charge-mass.html) Technical details and mathematical literature are also provided.

Comment: Known open problems aren't really appropriate for the site; they (loosely) fall under the 'open-ended discussion' heading. In a case like this, a more appropriate question might be something like 'what's the current state of progress on the rational tangle quantization question?', preferably with some information on what you currently know about the problem so that potential answerers can restrict their answers to the parts you aren't already familiar with. Further, posting a link to a prize page is going to inevitably come off as advertisement.

Comment: I rephrased as you proposed.

Comment: Just for clarification: advertizing has the aim to earn money. There is no advertizing involved here. Prizes have the opposite aim: to give money to others.